# Is there any way to access the current test's parameters (apart from the parameters themselves)?

Tags: nunit, parameterized-tests

If I write a parameterized NUnit test, using something like [`[TestCaseSource]`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) or [`[ValueSource]`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=valueSource&r=2.5), NUnit will pass the parameters directly to my test method. But is there any other way to access those parameters, e.g. from `SetUp`, or from a helper method (without having to explicitly pass the parameter value to that helper method)?

For example, suppose I have three different scenarios (maybe it's "rising rates", "falling rates", and "constant rates"). I'm writing tests for a particular calculation, and some tests will have the same behavior in all three scenarios; others in two of the three (and I'll write a second test for the other scenario); others will have a separate test for each scenario. Parameterized tests seem like a good way to model this; I can write a strategy object for each scenario, and parameterize the tests based on which scenarios each test should apply to.

I can do something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<RateStrategy> AllScenarios {
    get {
        yield return new RisingRatesStrategy();
        yield return new FallingRatesStrategy();
        yield return new ConstantRatesStrategy();
    }
}
[TestCaseSource("AllScenarios")]
public void SomethingThatIsTheSameInAllScenarios(RateStrategy scenario) {
    InitializeScenario(scenario);
    ... arrange ...
    ... act ...
    ... assert ...
}
```

The downside to this is that I need to remember to call `InitializeScenario` in every test. This is easy to mess up, and it also makes the tests harder to read -- in addition to the attribute that says exactly which scenarios this test applies to, I also need an extra line of code cluttering up my test, saying that oh yeah, there are scenarios.

Is there some other way I could access the test parameters? Is there a static property, similar to those on [`TestContext`](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6.2), that would let me access the test's parameters from, say, my `SetUp` method, so I could make my tests more declarative (convention-based) and less repetitive?

(`TestContext` looked promising, but it only tells me the test's name and whether it passed or failed. The test's parameters are sort of there, but only as part of a display string, not as actual objects; I can't grab the strategy object and start calling methods on it.)

Comment: Not the cleanest way, but probably possible via reflection. I don't think NUnit can do that out of the box.